# How to get call end notification event from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I tell in my app when a phone call has ended? Also, can I get information about that call, like the duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really good question. It might be possible to sign up to receive notifications (using `UINotificationCenter` calls) from `UITelephony` or similar. However, I don't know if that's a public or private API off the top of my head. Or if it's even possible :)

However, if you're actively using your app when the phone call starts, it will call `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground` when the call is finished. As for differentiating a phone call end versus just a regular return to phone call, I don't know. But it's a start.

As for duration, just save the time stamp including seconds to `NSUserDefaults` when `-(void)applicationWillResignActive`. Then compare and do math with the time stamp when `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground`. I hope this helps a bit, or at least sets you on the right track.

Comment: I would like to tell that
My application not run/run in background at time of call.

Comment: Apps run in the background automatically with a phone call. -(void)applicationWillResign active is called when going to the call, and -(void)applicationWillEnterForeground when returning from the phone call... It also uses those notifications when simply backgrounding normally, so that's something you'll have to figure out.